# Prevent particular Action method from being overriden by base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a controller class inheriting a base class that handles/overrides a virtual method (say JsonResult), and in this controller I need to prevent a  specific JsonResult method (and only this one) from being overriden by this base class. Creating an action filter attribute for the rest of the controller methods would be the last thing I wanna do. How would you do this?

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller 
{
    protected override JsonResult Json(...) { 
        //do something here
    }
}

public class HomeController : ControllerBase 
{
    public JsonResult UpdateData(...) { 
        return base.Json(...); // I need to prevent this method from being overriden
    }

    public JsonResult UpdateResult(...) { 
        return this.Json(...); // this (and the other ones) can use the base method.
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code and explain what do you mean by `prevent a specific method from being overriden by this base class`

Comment: "overridden by the base class" ? A derived class can override a method of the base class, not the other way round... Please clarify (and show some code).

Comment: Well, is the downvote really necessary ? But anyway, question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can not edit your base controller, you can instead use the `Controller.Content` method passing your object formatted in the JSON format.

To convert your object in JSON you can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class, as follows:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string jsonString = jsSerializer.Serialize(objectToSerialize);
```

Then you can return the result via the `Content` method, as follows:

```
return Content(jsonString, "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a flag in your base controller that you will use to control the method to call, like this:

```
public class ControllerBase : Controller 
{
    protected bool useOverriddenMethod = true;

    protected override JsonResult Json(...) {
        if (useOverriddenMethod )
        {
            //do something here
        }
        else
        {
            return base.Json(...);
        }
    }
}
```

And then set the flag accordingly when you need it:

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase 
{
    public JsonResult UpdateData(...) { 
        useOverriddenMethod = false;
        return this.Json(...); // I need to prevent this method from being overriden
    }

    public JsonResult UpdateResult(...) { 
        return this.Json(...); // this (and the other ones) can use the base method.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have write-permission to the base class file, so I wonder if there's any kind of attribute/action filter that allows you to do just this?

Comment: Ok I understand you problem, please read the other reply that I just added